# Unable to select checkboxes from SwfTreeView

Tags: qtp, hp-uft, uft-api

In my application there is a swfTreeView object which has 2 parent check boxes [Total, Systmatic] and both parent has 2 more child check boxes [ EQ, FX for Total and EX,IR for Systematic] . I am unable to select these checkboxes. I tried below way to select it but it didnt work

1. `swfWindow().SwfTreeView().Select "Total"`
2. `swfWindow().SwfTreeView().GetItemCount` and GetItem but got 0 results
3. Did recording but after rerun it didnt select

Questions:

1. What are the other ways to select expected checkbox?
2. 'Total' checkbox is by default selected. So How to deselect it before selecting other expected checkboxes?