# UFT :: Unable to select checkboxes from SWFTREEVIEW

Tags: qtp, hp-uft, uft14

I want to select check boxes which are in SwfTreeView. I tried to get getitem and getitemcount and it is returning 0. Below is the hierarchy of object
SwfWindow().SwfWindow().SwfTreeView("swfname:=treeListVarTypes")

Please suggest possible ways to select checkboxes from SwfTreeView.
Check boxes are like
Systematic is parent and SPREAD, NON SPREAD are their childs.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Unable to select checkboxes from SwfTreeView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70516547/unable-to-select-checkboxes-from-swftreeview)